# How i can get number in Json file

Tags: c#, json, request

Hi I am getting data and inserting into datagridview. I'm stuck where it can't be displayed, when I insert the data "fan_count" it shows the number "0" or because the number of fan_count is correct.

I use xNet and Newtonsoft.Json libraries to do this
I use Request to Api and get the following json file (I can't reveal the api, please forgive me)

JSON FILE I USE: https://hastebin.com/cavudotije.json

```
        string data = [LINK][1]
        PageLike getGroup = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PageLike>(data);

        foreach (var item in getGroup.Data)
        {
            pictureBox1.Load(item.Picture.Data.Url);
            dgv_FanpageList.Rows.Add(pictureBox1.Image, item.Name, item.Id, item.Category, item.FanCount, item.FollowersCount);
            //MessageBox.Show(item.FanCount.ToString()); - Test Msb
        }
```

Comment: Maybe "fan_cout" vs "fan_count" ? Missing "n" ?

Comment: Provide us with the JSON that you are using.

Comment: Here bro: https://hastebin.com/cavudotije.json

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the link to the external site (https://hastebin.com/cavudotije.json) is dead, and question still not answered.